# What is the correct way to suppress WM_ERASEBKGND?

Tags: winapi, doublebuffered

If I need to use double buffering, I need to suppress `WM_ERASEBKGND` message.

I can handle `WM_ERASEBKGND` and return immediately. But can I set the `WNDCLASS`/`WNDCLASSEX`'s `hbrBackground` to `NULL` and not handle the `WM_ERASEBKGND` message? Is this a correct way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, setting `hbrBackground` to `NULL` is an appropriate way to avoid implementing a no-op `WM_ERASEBKGND` handler.

When you pass `WM_ERASEBKGND` on to `DefWindowProc`, it checks the background brush in the window's class.  If there is one, it fills the dirty region with it.  If the background brush is null, it does nothing and returns.  That's essentially the same as having your own do-nothing `WM_ERASEBKGND` handler.

The return value from the `WM_ERASEBKGND` handler affects the `fErase` field of the `PAINTSTRUCT` you get when `WM_PAINT` calls `BeginPaint`.  The `WM_PAINT` handler is supposed to check `fErase` to find out whether it needs to erase the background itself or if it was already done by `WM_ERASEBKGND`.  (Though I've never actually seen anyone check it.)  If you let `DefWindowProc` handle `WM_ERASEBKGND` it will return `TRUE` if it has a color number or brush and `FALSE` if the `hbrBackground` is `NULL`.

Comment: Note that you are __still__ sent a `WM_ERASEBKGND` then. Only difference is if you don't handle it, nothing happens (safe to ignore).

Comment: Are you certain that this is a kosher method?  Do you know why [Raymond Chen seems to make a distinction](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140305-00/?p=1593/) between using `NULL` and the hollow brush?

Comment: Yes, it's kosher.  Of `hbrBackground`, MSDN says, "When this member is NULL, an application must paint its own background whenever it is requested to paint in its client area."

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy I meant: are you sure that it's kosher to set `hbrBackground` to `NULL` *and* to not handle `WM_ERASEBKGND` (the original question).  The MSDN documentation you cited does say "an application *must* paint its own background ...". (Your comments on [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41029315/179715) make sense, though.)

Comment: "...whenever it is requested to paint in its client area."  Which suggests that doing it in WM_PAINT is fine.  WM_ERASEBKGND is sent by the BeginPaint call (if the invalid region is also marked for erasure), so it's already happening in the WM_PAINT handler.  And to make sure theory matches practice, I've just tested it.  if hbrBackground is NULL, DefWindowProc's handling for WM_ERASEBKGND is to do nothing but return FALSE.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it is more correct to set `hbrBackground = GetStockObject(HOLLOW_BRUSH)` than it is to set it to `NULL`.

[An article on Raymond Chen's The Old New Thing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140305-00/?p=1593/) makes a distinction:

> If you don't want automatic background drawing, then pass the hollow brush. If you want custom background drawing, then pass `NULL` as the brush.

[The MSDN documentation for `WNDCLASS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633576.aspx)'s `hbrBackground` member says:

> When this member is `NULL`, an application must paint its own background whenever it is requested to paint in its client area. To determine whether the background must be painted, an application can either process the `WM_ERASEBKGND` message or test the `fErase` member of the `PAINTSTRUCT` structure filled by the `BeginPaint` function.

And the [MSDN documentation for `WM_ERASEBKGND`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648055.aspx) says:

> The `DefWindowProc` function erases the background by using the class background brush specified by the `hbrBackground` member of the `WNDCLASS` structure. If `hbrBackground` is `NULL`, the application should process the `WM_ERASEBKGND` message and erase the background.

My interpretation is that setting `hbrBackground` to `NULL` and then neglecting to handle `WM_ERASEBKGND` not meant to be strictly legal (but probably works); `hbrBackground = NULL` is a promise that you will handle `WM_ERASEBKGND` yourself and not let `DefWindowProc` try to paint with a null pointer.

Comment: I think you're over analyzing it.  Setting hbrBackground to NULL does the right thing.  You can either fill the background yourself by handling WM_ERASEBKGND or you can do it in WM_PAINT.  DefWindowProc for WM_ERASEBKGND returns TRUE if there was a brush (or color) specified and it filled the area.  It returns FALSE if hbrBackground was NULL.  No harm.

Comment: I think the distinction is what happens to the fErase member of the PAINTSTRUCT you get from BeginPaint.  If you have a hollow brush selected, the default WM_ERASEBKGND handler will fill with the hollow brush and return TRUE (meaning "I erased the background).  That causes the fErase member to be FALSE, so the rest of the WM_PAINT handler isn't tricked into doing it's own erasing.  If you have NULL, the default WM_ERASEBKGND handler does nothing and returns FALSE ("I did NOT erase the background"), which causes the fErase member to be TRUE.

Comment: In the documentation for PAINTSTRUCT, under fErase, it says:  "The application is responsible for erasing the background if a window class is created without a background brush."  So it's legit to not have a backround brush at all.  Here, "the application" refers to the WM_PAINT handler, because by the time you get the PAINTSTRUCT from BeginPaint, WM_ERASEBKGND has come and gone.  Yes, you're still responsible for painting the background, but the WM_PAINT handler is a legit place to do it.